# Integrating Microsoft Bot Framework with Node Express Web site

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am experimenting with the [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/). In my experiment, I'm trying to integrate "[Hello World](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/overview/#navtitle)" into an existing web app. My web app is an express Node.js app.

In my Node.js app, I want to have a web page that has a text box that let's me send a message to a bot. Basically, I'm trying to imitate the framework channel emulator in a web page. In an attempt to do this, I have a webpage with the following:

**bot.html**

```
<form>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="message" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="sendButton" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">send</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

...

```
$('#sendButton').click(onSendButtonClick);
function onSendButtonClick() {
    var message = $('#message').val();
    if (message) {
        $.post('/my-bot', function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, on the server side, in my Node.js app, which is using Express, I have the following:

```
// This route is intended to listen for messages POSTed from the text box on my web site.
app.post('/my-bot', function(req, res) {
    try {
        // Not sure about this...
        let connector = new BotBuilder.ConsoleConnector().listen();            
        let bot = new BotBuilder.UniversalBot(connector );
        bot.dialog('/', function (session) {                
            session.send('Hello World');
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        res.status(500);
        res.end();
    }
});

// The following serves up my web page
app.use('/my-bot', function(req, res) { 
    let view = './bot.html';        
    res.render(view, {});
});
```

I'm not sure how to get "Hello World" back to my web page. I see the call to `session.send`, but I don't see a way to connect `session` to the `res` object. Or am I misunderstanding the architecture altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Direct Line API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/).

> The Direct Line API is a simple REST API for connecting directly to a single bot. This API is intended for developers writing their own client applications, web chat controls, mobile apps, or service-to-service applications that will talk to their bot

Comment: Link is broken now

Answer (score 2):

The callback in your `app.post` should be `connector.listen()`, and you should only define/call `connector` a single time. Calling `connector.listen()` will return a function suitable for express-style callbacks, and because your connector is wired up to `bot`, your bot dialog routes will be activated on POST.

Here is a sample app:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = process.env.HTTPS == 'on' ? require('https') : require('http')
  , builder = require('botbuilder');

var app = express()
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , port = process.env.port || 3000
  , config = { appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID, appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD }
  , connector = new builder.ChatConnector(config)
  , bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

// define bot dialog routes
bot.dialog('/', function(session) {
  session.send('Hello World');
});

// define app HTTP routes
app

  // respond to basic HTTP GET
  .get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello world');
  })

  // respond to bot messages
  .post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// start the server
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on %s', port);
});
```

And I see that you are attempting to handle potential errors. If you need to communicate a failure to the client, you should call `session.error()` in lieu of `session.send()`:

```
bot.dialog('/', function (session) {

  // do some processing
  var gotError = true;

  // respond with error
  if (gotError) {
    session.error(new Error('oops'))

  // respond normally
  } else {
    session.send('Hello World');
  }
});
```